# AttributeError: 'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'callbacks'

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, xgboost

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\VScode\WorkProjects\2022\Product_Classification\retention_ml.py", line 169, in output_result
result_28 = xgboost_reg_281.predict(data[col_reg_28])
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1047, in predict
if self._can_use_inplace_predict():
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 983, in _can_use_inplace_predict
predictor = self.get_params().get("predictor", None)
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 636, in get_params
params.update(cp.**class**.get_params(cp, deep))
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 633, in get_params
params = super().get_params(deep)
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ppy39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 205, in get_params
value = getattr(self, key)
AttributeError: 'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'callbacks'

Comment: who can tell me how to slove it ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi James, please add some relevant code. A traceback alone will not help us reproduce this issue

Answer (score 8):

Check your xgboost library version. I loaded a model saved from xgboost==1.5.0 env to a xgboost==1.6.0 env and got the same error when operating on the model. I downgraded xgboost to 1.5.0 and everything worked fine. I suspect the model saving format is changing since 1.6.0 as it gives warning about me loading a binary model file using pickle dump.

Comment: Exactly. Either train your model using xgboost >= 1.6 and use xgboost >= 1.6 when predicting == during inference (ideally always the same versions), or train with xgboost < 1.6 and then also use a version prior to 1.6 during inference.

Answer (score 4):

We made:

```
!pip install xgboost==1.5.0
```

And it ran perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use xgboost version 1.6 you can simply do the following:

```
new_attrs = ['grow_policy', 'max_bin', 'eval_metric', 'callbacks', 'early_stopping_rounds', 'max_cat_to_onehot', 'max_leaves', 'sampling_method']

for attr in new_attrs:
    setattr(xgb_model, attr, None)
```

This sets all the parameters that are in 1.6 but not in 1.5. All of them are typed as Optional so as far as I can tell None is fine. Results are consistent.

If you get complaints about the model being an old version (and you used pickle), you can create a virtual environment with the old xgboost version and an environment with the new version. Then, in the old version, do:

```
import pickle

with open("xgb_model_1_5.p", "rb") as rf:
    xgb = pickle.load(rf)
    bst = xgb.get_booster()
    bst.save_model("booster")
```

And then in the 1.6 virtual environment:

```
import pickle

with open("xgb_model_1_5.p", "rb") as rf:
    xgb = pickle.load(rf)
    bst = xgb.get_booster()
    bst.load_model("booster")

with open("xgb_model_1_6.p", "wb") as wf:
    pickle.dump(xgb, wf)
```